# Share editing on documents and folders on Onedrive

Tags: file-sharing, onedrive, synchronization

With Dropbox when I add a new document (.txt, .docx etc) to that folder, those documents will be synced to other participants in that shared folder.
Whenever that other participant changes that document, I will automatically get the latest version in my Dropbox folder.

Simple enough, but in OneDrive this doesn't seem to work.

First of all, when someone shares a folder with me, that folder is NOT synced to my local PC and I also can't see it when I try to choose the folders I want to sync via the Onedrive client. Also via the OneDrive web interface I don't see the shared folder under the 'Shared' menu on the left side.

When someone shares an individual Word document with me, I can download it, but then downloads it not to my OneDrive folder, but my regular downloads folder, so it's no longer in the shared folder (very annoying). Or I can edit it via Word Online, which I really don't want.

So basically: how to do folder/file sharing AND editing in OneDrive like on Dropbox? Is it even possible? Right now it's a mess and confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the new Microsoft roadmap reveals when it's coming...please hurry up Microsoft, I want to dump Dropbox :)
See more details here: http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-fills-in-onedrive-roadmap-dates-details/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do it.

Yes, very annoying.

No idea why MS hasn't offered this feature.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsharing/onedrive-shared-folder-sync-to-desktop/f6e69fbc-ada4-4faf-9790-fd0604262f56